# Function improperly marks CSV rows as corrupt

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with data in it that should be either a float or an integer, but if its not, the row is marked as corrupt.
I have this if statement that checks several of the columns in each row to see if they are not empty, and if they are a float or integer. Currently, the program marks every row in the CSV file as corrupt. How do I fix this?

```
def check_if_number(num) :
    for i in num:
        if i == "." or i == "":
            pass
        else:
            try:
                float(i)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                return False
            return True

def check_if_empty(item) :
    if item == "" :
        return True
    else:
        return False

if (check_if_empty(row[5]) == False
and check_if_number(row[5]) == False
or check_if_empty(row[6]) == False
and check_if_number(row[6]) == False 
or check_if_empty(row[8]) == False
and check_if_number(row[8]) == False 
or check_if_empty(row[9]) == False
and check_if_number(row[9]) == False 
or check_if_empty(row[10]) == False
and check_if_number(row[10]) == False):
    corrupt = True
```

Comment: Second line in your code has indentation error. Are u running this exact same code?

Comment: My mistake, I'm not running that exact code, I've fixed the post.

Comment: You can simplify this nasty if statement by defining a list like `col_num_list = [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]` and then use if statement like this `for col_num in col_num_list: if check_if_empty(row[col_num]) == False and check_if_number(row[col_num]`

Comment: Thanks, this helps simplify my loop but doesn't fix my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a dummy  row so that ppl can have a look at the kind of data types you r handling here?

Comment: A row would have values such as 77 | 77s | 4%4 | 100 | A | 55

Answer (score 1):

I think your second function is returning True when you want it to return False?

```
def check_if_empty(item) :
    if item == "" :
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

EDIT:
I have simplified and attached an updated working code that yields what you are looking for just to help substantiate my thought.

```
def check_if_number(num):
    float(num)
    for i in num:
        if i == "." or i == "":
            pass
        else:
            try:
                float(i)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                return False
            return True

def check_if_empty(item):
    if item == "" :
        return False
    else:
        return True

if check_if_empty('.4') == True and check_if_number('.4') == True:
    corrupt = False
else:
    corrupt = True

print(corrupt)
... False
```

Comment: This is not the issue, it is meant to return True when the list is empty.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more code, I still think your issue is some weird double negative type boolean jujitsu.